# Font issues on Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, fonts

I have issues with two specific fonts on Ubuntu.

1. Calibri: The font is very small (around 1/2 the size of other fonts) and as a result, quite visibly pixelated.
2. Monaco: In multiple lines of text, it tends to fold up over itself. Even firebug, using Monaco for the code, folds up on itself.

Does anyone know how to fix these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Monaco issue seems to be fixed in Ubuntu 9.10. Calibri still looks like crap, but that's apparently because it uses font hinting which ubuntu doesn't support.